# AppHarbor not compressing assets

Tags: nginx, servicestack, gzip, appharbor

I'm running a serviceStack web service with an Angular front end on AppHarbor, Apparently assets are meant to be gzipped out of the box, but none are, dynamic nor static, images, css, js, html...

What am I missing? there doesn't seem to be any configuration available to turn this on or off, any suggestions?